# How to group by using timestamp?

Tags: mysql

I have an dataset as follows,

```
  Timestamp         User          Topup
3/22/2022 14:24:10      John        10
3/23/2022 14:25:10      John        11
3/24/2022 14:28:10      John        12
3/25/2022 15:24:10      John        13
3/26/2022 15:27:10      John        14
3/27/2022 17:24:10      John        15
3/28/2022 18:24:10      John        16
3/29/2022 20:24:10      John        17
3/30/2022 20:26:10      Mike        18
3/31/2022 21:24:10      Mike        19
4/1/2022 22:24:10       Mike        20
```

I need to group each user's total topup by considering the timstamp. But I need 15 minutes time duration. SO the output should look like below,

```
Time Range          User  Total Topup
2022-03-22 14.00    John        0
2022-03-22 14.15    John        33
2022-03-22 14.00    Mike        0
2022-03-22 14.15    Mike        0
2022-03-22 14.30    John        0
2022-03-22 14.30    Mike        0
2022-03-22 14.45    John        0
2022-03-22 15.00    Mike        0
```

The `2022-03-22 14.00` represents all the topups of each user in 2022-03-22 14:00 to 2022-03-22 14:15. Here is my try, but I am stuck with applying the time range to group the data. Can someone help me?

```
select User, sum(Topup) from revenuetable group by User;
```

Update:I would like to use statements without window functions

Comment: Generate your 15-min values then join the data to this datetimes set and aggregate.

Comment: Could you please help me with an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to round to the nearest 15 minutes. We extract the time without the minutes of seconds. We divide the number of minutes by 15, using DIV to force integer division, which gives 0, 1, 2 or 3. We can add 15 times this number of minutes to round up rather than down. We use this in the sub-query to round the times, which we then use to group the entries.

> ```
> create table users (
> ts Timestamp,
> Username varchar(10),
> Topup int);
> insert into users values
> ('2022-3-22 14:14:10','John', 10),
> ('2022-3-22 14:15:10','John', 11),
> ('2022-3-22 14:18:10','John', 12),
> ('2022-3-22 15:24:10','John', 13),
> ('2022-3-22 14:27:10','John', 14),
> ('2022-3-22 14:24:10','John', 15),
> ('2022-3-22 14:24:10','John', 16),
> ('2022-3-22 14:24:10','John', 17),
> ('2022-3-22 14:34:10','John', 10),
> ('2022-3-22 14:35:10','John', 11),
> ('2022-3-22 14:48:10','John', 12),
> ('2022-3-22 14:44:10','John', 13),
> ('2022-3-22 14:57:10','John', 14),
> ('2022-3-22 14:54:10','John', 15),
> ('2022-3-22 14:24:10','John', 16),
> ('2022-3-22 14:24:10','John', 17),
> ('2022-3-22 14:26:10 ','Mike', 18),
> ('2022-3-22 14:24:10 ','Mike', 19),
> ('2022-3-22 14:24:10 ','Mike', 20);
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   username, 
>   rounded_time,
>   sum(topUp)
> from (
> select 
>   username,
>       DATE_ADD(
>         DATE_FORMAT(ts, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"),
>         INTERVAL (MINUTE(ts) DIV 15) * 15 + 15  MINUTE
>     ) AS rounded_time,
>     topUp
> from users ) u
> group by username, rounded_time
> order by rounded_time, username
> ```
>
> ```
> username | rounded_time        | sum(topUp)
> :------- | :------------------ | ---------:
> John     | 2022-03-22 14:15:00 |         10
> John     | 2022-03-22 14:30:00 |        118
> Mike     | 2022-03-22 14:30:00 |         57
> John     | 2022-03-22 14:45:00 |         34
> John     | 2022-03-22 15:00:00 |         41
> John     | 2022-03-22 15:30:00 |         13
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=faeeaae77d16dfc9c54f2a3156f55001)*

Comment: Note that this use of `INTERVAL` will round the datetimes **down**; so for values between 1400 and 1415 they will appear at interval 1400 rather than at interval 1415.

Comment: If you want to round up either add 1 before multiplying or 15 afterwards. See updated answer.

Comment: But how this can be use to get what i required?

Comment: please see modified answer